# Tableview not reloading data properly not rendering cells on reload

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

This is my API fetch code and it's returning data successfully and also updating the array correctly.

```
API.shared.fetchAccomodations(completion: { (accResponse, error) in

        if let err = error {

            print("Failed to fetch accommodation information ::" , err.localizedDescription)
        }
        if let response = accResponse {

            self.accomodationsData = response

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.accomodationsData = response

                print(self.accomodationsData.count , self.accomodationsData)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

                 }

        }


      }, tokenURL: accomodationsURL)
```

Comment: Can you add in your code for [cellForRowAt](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview)

Comment: Why do you set the data source twice? o.O

Comment: @RakeshaShastri just tried a hook but thats not causing problem because after and before I was testing without that

Comment: @DoesData thats a big function because I'M CONFIGURING TWO TABLEVIEWS in it

Comment: That code is really relevant to your question. We can see you're calling reload, but we know nothing about the tableview datasource so how can we determine what is going wrong? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Ok let me put that here

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView ==  courseInfoTableView {
                if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "courseCell", for: indexPath) as? CourseInfoCell {

Comment: }
        else if tableView == self.tableView{
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AccomodationCell", for: indexPath) as? AccomodationCell {

                cell.titleLabel.text = AccomodationData[indexPath.row].residenceName

Comment: What I concluded is that there is problem with background fetch because when I run it in debug mode sometimes it works like It shows data but without breakpoints no chancee.
I shown the code to one senior also and he said the issue is with background fetch API

Comment: But then I think that how URLSession can be buggy. hard to believe

Comment: You should edit the question to add the necessary information. Also format your code properly so that it is easily readable. Look at the other questions posted to check how to format code. No one will spend time reading unreadable code. If no one reads your question you won't get an answer :/

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView ==  courseInfoTableView { }

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { if tableView == courseInfoTableView {
}

else if tableView == self.tableView{
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AccomodationCell", for: indexPath) as? AccomodationCell {

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
if tableView == courseInfoTableView { 
// assign this tableview outlets
}
 else if tableView == self.tableView{ 
if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AccomodationCell", for: indexPath) as? AccomodationCell { 
// assign this table outlets
// This is the tableview for which I'm fetching the data 
}

Comment: I think It's readable now I have tried to make indentations but after adding comment they get removed. Hopefully you understood whaT i'M DOING.
i HAVE TWO TABLEVIEWS basically.